# Terraform error "Your query returned no results"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have below bom-asg.tf file.

```
data "aws_ami" "bom-ami" {
most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "tag:ami_name"
    values = ["${var.environment}-bom-ami"]
  }

  owners = ["****"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "bom-sg" {
  name_prefix = "${var.environment}-bom-asg-sg"
  vpc_id      = "${var.vpc_id}"
  .....
```

I am unable to successfully execute refresh and plan commands. I am getting below errors.

```
terraform plan --var-file=environment-parity.tfvars -target=bom-asg.tf --out apply.out
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

But when I run refresh. I am getting below error.

```
terraform refresh --var-file=environment-parity.tfvars
data.template_file.es_access_policy_search: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.nginx-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.php-search-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.ng-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.mysql-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.frontend-search-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.bom-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.lg-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.rabbitmq-search-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.ngas-ng-drupal-ami: Refreshing state...
data.aws_ami.mongodb-ami: Refreshing state...

Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_ami.bom-ami: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.aws_ami.bom-ami: data.aws_ami.bom-ami: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Can you please run aws ec2 describe-images 
 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html) with the same filter parameters in your TF script? Please be specific with **region** as AMI image may not be found due to region difference. Usually I get the "no result" because the filter string does not match the AMI images available in a specific region.

Comment: @mon Image is not available because it has not yet been created. I was running apply command but getting same error. I am expecting apply command creates AMI. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terraform **data source** is to access an existing resource, not to create one.

```
data "aws_ami" "bom-ami"
```

As in the documentation, the AMI needs to exist already.

- [Data Source: aws_ami](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html)

> Use this data source to get the ID of a **registered** AMI for use in other resources.

If you are creating an AMI from an EBS snapshot taken from an EC2 instance (e.g. Amazon Linux EC2), then:

- [Resource: aws_ami](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ami.html)

Please note the difference between **data** and **resource**.

To create a custom AMI image, please also consider [Hashicorp packer](https://packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image.html).