# Your query returned no results

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I am using below code to create an Elastic Beanstalk env. Now I am getting error suddenly. It was working fine, getting issue since I have restarted jenkins. terraform apply commands is running from jenkins. terraform data part is from main.tf. For more info - I am installing terraform using below command line. I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280384/terraform-error-your-query-returned-no-results), but scenario is different.

```
sh 'wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.5/terraform_0.14.5_linux_amd64.zip'
sh 'unzip terraform_0.14.5_linux_amd64.zip
sh 'mv ./terraform /usr/bin/'
sh 'terraform init'
sh "terraform apply -auto-approve -var \'env=${ENVNAME}\' -var \'appversion=${APPVERSION}\' -var \'sshkey=${SSHKEY}\'" 


data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack" "multi_docker" {
  most_recent = true

  name_regex = "^64bit Amazon Linux (.*) Multi-container Docker (.*)$"
}



 Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack.multi_docker: Refreshing state...

Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using so old terraform version? Can you try with newer?

Comment: I tried with latest terraform version. Still same error. Let me update the question

Comment: The query in itself is correct. Maybe there is no support for multidocker in your region?

Comment: Yes you are correct, Thanks. needed to set aws region. Would you like to provide this as an answer.

Comment: What region are you trying to use? I also guessed that but when I iterated through the AWS regions (not govcloud/China) they all returned a stack matching that pattern.

Comment: For reference I tested with the following command `for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].RegionName' --output text); do echo $region; aws --region $region elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks --query 'SolutionStacks' --output text | tr '\t' '\n'| grep -E '^64bit Amazon Linux (.*) Multi-container Docker (.*)$'; done`.

Comment: the default region was not set. So I have to do "aws configure"

Comment: If there's no default region set then Terraform's AWS provider will prompt for the region when you run it. It won't just run with no region set and then fail with an obscure error.

Comment: Thanks. The answer was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The `aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack` is correct. However, multidocker container EB environments are **not supported in all regions**. The solution was to use a region which has support for the multidocker containers.